# Difference between inverted page table and a standard one?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, paging

I know that for standard page tables each process would have its own page table and for inverted the OS would have it.

But other than this what are the main differences between a standard page table and an inverted one?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this inverted page table is to reduce the amount of physical memory needed to track virtual-to-physical address translations. We accomplish this savings by creating a table that has one entry per page of physical memory, indexed by the pair <process-id, page-number>. Because they keep information about which virtual memory page is stored in each physical frame, inverted page tables reduce the amount of physical memory needed to store this information.
[image: inverted page table]

Each inverted page-table entry is a pair <process-id, page-number> where the
process-id assumes the role of the address-space identifier. When a memory
reference occurs, part of the virtual address, consisting of <process-id, page-number>, is presented to the memory subsystem. The inverted page table is then searched for a match. If a match is found—say, at entry i— then the physical address <i, offset> is generated. If no match is found, then an illegal address access has been attempted.

Although this scheme **decreases** the **amount of memory** needed to store
each page table, it **increases** the amount of **time** needed to search the table when a page reference occurs. (because we might search the whole table to find a match).

Also with inverted page tables, only one mapping of a virtual address to the shared physical address may occur a any given time. A reference by another process sharing the memory will result in a page fault and will replace the mapping with a different virtual address.

---

More information : Operating System Concepts, 10th Edition | Abraham Silberschatz, Greg Gagne, Peter B. Galvin

Comment: How many logical addresses/pages can usefully be mapped to a single physical address? Shared memory; pages initially zeroed&"copied" on write, …

Comment: @greybeard I don't know if I completely got your question or not but as I figured, using standard paging each process has its own page table, which allows multiple virtual memory addresses to be mapped to same physical address. This is not true in inverted page table; because there is only one virtual page entry for every physical page, one physical page cannot have two (or more) shared virtual addresses.